# how to update parent widget after showDialog is closed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a widget with an icon when I click on it a dialog widget is shown, here is the call for the dialog :

```
// this icon is in widget parent
           IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.info_outline,
                size: mobileWidth * 0.07,
              ),
              tooltip: 'information',
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              onPressed: () {
                showAlertInfo(context, code);
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
```

here is my dialog :

```
showAlertInfo(BuildContext context, String code) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              "Information sur le client $code", ),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
               child: Container( ..... 
               /* ...
               this dialog has some operations that changes info 
               values of the widget that called this in first place
               it is a big code to put here*/
             // here I have a close button
                    actions: [
            FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "Fermer",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
                fontSize: mobileWidth * 0.035,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
```

what I'm trying to achieve is when the dialog is dismissed I want the parent widget to be updated, so how I call `setState` of the parent widget when the dialog widget is closed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For Async function

Add `await` before `showDialog()` and call `setState((){})` on the next line.

```
await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
       return yourWidget;
    }
);
setState((){});
```

### For  Sync Function

Use the `.then()` callback, and call `setState((){})` in it.

```dart
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder(context) {
        return yourWidget;
    }).then((_){
        setState((){});
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , can you take a look at my similar question pleas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054185/how-to-update-a-widget-state-from-another-widget-in-flutter-using-global-key